# How to capture output(JSON) data from powershell in python

Tags: python, azure, powershell

I am trying to capture part of output data which is in json form from python script. powershell command is

`az ad sp create-for-rbac`

Out put is in below format

```
The underlying Active Directory Graph API will be replaced by Microsoft Graph API in a future version of Azure CLI. Please carefully review all breaking changes introduced during this migration: https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/microsoft-graph-migration
The output includes credentials that you must protect. Be sure that you do not include these credentials in your code or check the credentials into your source control. For more information, see https://aka.ms/azadsp-cli
{
  "appId": "xxxxxxxx",
  "displayName": "xxxxxxx",
  "password": "xxxxx",
  "tenant": "xxxxx"
}
```

I want to capture json part particularly appId, and password field

I have tried using subprocess but don't know how to capture json part as its only capturing text part in the output.
Can somebody please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Output data of my command produces bytes data sequence. which I captured using following command

```
result = subprocess.run(['az', 'ad', 'sp', 'create-for-rbac'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```